# I'm not sure how to round this properly in my Java code

Tags: java, rounding

I'm fairly new to Java, and I've recently written a code that calculates how much change you would need for x amount of money payed for a y priced item. It works well; my only issue is that whenever there is not any change owed in the hundredths place (ex: $4.60), it will round down to the tenths place ($4.6).

If anybody knows how to fix this, I would be very grateful. I have the code posted below.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      double x;
      double y;
      double z;

      System.out.print("Enter the price of the product: $");
      x = scan.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Enter what you payed with: $");
      y = scan.nextDouble();
      z = (int)Math.round(100*(y-x));

      System.out.print("Change Owed: $");
      System.out.println((z)/100);

      int q = (int)(z/25);
      int d = (int)((z%25/10));
      int n = (int)((z%25%10/5));
      int p = (int)(z%25%10%5);

      System.out.println("Quarters: " + q);
      System.out.println("Dimes: " + d);
      System.out.println("Nickels: " + n);
      System.out.println("Pennies: " + p);

    }
}
```

Edit: Thank you to everyone that answered my question! I ended up going with DecimalFormat to solve it, and now it works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call something like this:

```
String.format("%.2f", i);
```

So in your case:

```
...
System.out.print("Change Owed: $");
System.out.println((String.format("%.2f", z)/100));
...
```

`String.format()` is useful whenever you want to round it to certain significant figures. In this case "f" stands for float.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is expected. You do not want numbers to carry trailing zeroes.
You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for representing them as a `String` with a trailing zero, rounded to two digits.

Example:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
double d = 4.7d;
System.out.println(df.format(d));

d = 5.678d;
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Output:

```
4.70
5.68
```

You can also add your currency sign to the `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");
```

Output with currency sign:

```
$4.70
$5.68
```

**EDIT:**

You can even tell [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) how to round your number by setting the [`RoundingMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) through `df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);`

Answer (score 1):

The [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method is my personal preference. For example:

```
float z;
System.out.println(String.format("Change Owed: $%.2f", (float) ((z) / 100)));
```

%.2f will round any float ('f' stands for float) off to 2 decimal places, by changing the number before the 'f' you change how many decimal points you round to. Eg:

```
//3 decimal points
System.out.println(String.format("Change Owed: $%.3f", (float) ((z) / 100)));

//4 decimal points
System.out.println(String.format("Change Owed: $%.4f", (float) ((z) / 100)));

// and so forth...
```

You may want to do some reading into [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) if you are starting out with Java. It is a very powerful and useful method.

From what I understand:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    System.out.print("Enter the price of the product: $");
    x = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter what you payed with: $");
    y = scan.nextDouble();
    z = (int) Math.round(100 * (y - x));

    System.out.println(String.format("Change Owed: $%.2f", (float) ((z) / 100)));

    int q = (int) (z / 25);
    int d = (int) ((z % 25 / 10));
    int n = (int) ((z % 25 % 10 / 5));
    int p = (int) (z % 25 % 10 % 5);

    System.out.println("Quarters: " + q);
    System.out.println("Dimes: " + d);
    System.out.println("Nickels: " + n);
    System.out.println("Pennies: " + p);
}
```

All the best for your future projects!

Comment: I would like to see some explanation as to why the `String.format()` method is his "best option". It sounds to me like you are spreading personal preference.